# regex options /i, etc not working in MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

This question is related to MongoDB Compass Community Version 1.17.0.

Code `{ location: /IL$|US$/i }` (with regex options) works with the Documents Filter tool, but with the Aggregations `$match` pipeline stage the application says `Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found.`

Code with no regex options, i.e., `{ location: /IL$|US$/ }` works in both the filter, and the aggregation tools.

How can I use regex options in the `$match` pipeline stage of MongoDB Compass?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the RegExp object, e.g.:

```
{
  email: RegExp('@gmail.com$', 'i')
}
```

Comment: What version of Compass are you using? I just tried the latest stable (1.20.3) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: it works for me by changing the indentation and keeping everything on one line. (Compass Version 1.21.2)

Comment: I noticed it doesn't work if you have more than one option in a single string. For example: `'ig'` needs to be broken up into `'i', 'g'`.

Comment: I also noticed that if the `RegExp()` query is not responding you have to sometimes close the tab for the collection, re-open it, and try the query again in a new tab to get it to work with the fixed query. I just reported this as a bug in jira.mongodb.org